# The instance member 'tmpFoto' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

Tags: flutter, dart

My plan, I will convert from String data type to File but I get error in ***File coba_coba = File(foto);***

```
part of 'models.dart';

class KirimBarangDetail extends Object {
  String id, headerId, itemId, itemNama, ukuranId, ukuranNama, noBox, berat, jumlah, beratInvoice, ukuranInvoice, ukuranInvoiceNama, beratMatiPacking, jumlahMatiPacking, keterangan, foto, fotoPath, statusUpload;
  File coba_coba = File(foto);  

  KirimBarangDetail({
    this.id,this.headerId,this.itemId,this.itemNama,this.ukuranId,this.ukuranNama,this.noBox,this.berat,this.jumlah,this.beratInvoice,this.ukuranInvoice,this.ukuranInvoiceNama,this.beratMatiPacking,this.jumlahMatiPacking,this.keterangan,this.foto,this.fotoPath,this.statusUpload, this.coba_coba,
  });
```

is there any solution with this case?

```
  KirimBarangDetail.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    this.id = map['id'].toString();this.headerId = map['id'].toString();this.itemId = map['item_id'].toString();this.itemNama = map['item_nama'];this.ukuranId = map['ukuran'].toString();this.ukuranNama = map['ukuran_nama'];this.noBox = map['no_box'].toString();this.berat = map['berat'].toString();this.jumlah = map['jumlah'].toString();this.beratInvoice = map['berat_invoice'].toString();this.ukuranInvoice = map['ukuran_invoice'].toString();this.ukuranInvoiceNama = map['ukuran_nama_invoice'];this.beratMatiPacking = map['berat_mati_packing'].toString();this.jumlahMatiPacking = map['jumlah_mati_packing'].toString();this.keterangan = map['keterangan'];this.foto = map['item_foto'];this.fotoPath = map['item_foto_path'];this.statusUpload = map['status_upload'];
  }

  Map toJson() => {
    'id': id,'kbarang_id': headerId,'item_id': itemId,'ukuran': ukuranId,'no_box': noBox,'berat': berat,'jumlah': jumlah,'berat_invoice': beratInvoice,'ukuran_invoice': ukuranInvoice,'berat_mati_packing': beratMatiPacking,'jumlah_mati_packing': jumlahMatiPacking,'keterangan': keterangan,'item_foto': foto,'file_name': foto,'imgData': fotoPath,
  };
}
```

Comment: Please show the error as text in the body of your question with an [edit].

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing an instance member by other in the initializer space. You can't use other members to initialize a new member. You could do this inside the constructor or any method defined inside class.

You can take reference from here

Wrong:

```
class Salary{
    int CTC;
    int inHand = CTC*0.8; // CTC can't be used here to intialize inHand.

    Salary(int CTC){
        this.CTC = CTC;
    }
}
```

Instead do like this

```
class Salary{
    int CTC;
    int inHand;

    Salary(int CTC){
        this.CTC = CTC;
        this.inHand = this.CTC * 0.8;
    }
}
```

Also you can do it in any other method created (but before using the inHand attribute).